# Is my algorithm correct? (Polar decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I cant seem to find my mistake. Consider this matrix $T = $\begin{bmatrix}
       2 & 1 & 1 \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 2 & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & -1
     \end{bmatrix}

I need the polar decomposition of $T$ ($T=AS$, with $A$ orthogonal and $S$ symmetrical). So, here are my steps:

- Calculate $T^TT=$\begin{bmatrix}
         5 & 0 & 2 \\[0.3em]
         0 & 6 & 0 \\[0.3em]
         2 & 0 & 2
       \end{bmatrix}
- Calculate eigenvalues of $T^TT$:
  $1,6,6$
- Calculate $S=\sqrt{T^TT}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&2\\ 0&1&0
  \\ -2&0&1\end {array} \right]\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&\sqrt{6}&0
  \\ 0&0&\sqrt{6}\end {array} \right]\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \frac{1}{5}&0&-\frac{2}{5}\\ 0&1&0
  \\ \frac{2}{5}&0&\frac{1}{5}\end {array} \right]=$\begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{6} & 0 & -\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{6} \\[0.3em]
         0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 \\[0.3em]
         -\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{6} & 0 & \frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{6}
       \end{bmatrix}

Now I get a really big matrix for $S^{-1}$ and an even bigger one for $A$. When I put my matrices in the equation $T=AS$ an error occurs.

Can you help me find my mistake(s)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "big matrix"? Usually when people talk about the size of a matrix, they mean how many rows and columns it has. All the matrices in your question are the same size.

Comment: Nevermind. It was correct all along. It was Maple's strange way to multiply matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have for $S$ is exactly correct. To make finding $S^{-1}$ easier, normalize your columns of your matrix of eigenvectors, so that $S = QDQ^{T}$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. Then $S^{-1} = QD^{-1}Q^{T}$ and all of the matrices in that product are easy to calculate.

In particular,
$$Q = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{5} & 0 & 2/\sqrt{5}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-2/\sqrt{5} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{5}\end{array}\right].$$

Then
$$S^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{5} & 0 & 2/\sqrt{5}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-2/\sqrt{5} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{5}\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1/\sqrt{6} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{6}\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{5} & 0 & -2/\sqrt{5}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
2/\sqrt{5} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{5}\end{array}\right].$$

Multiplying out gives that 
$$S^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/5+4/(5\sqrt{6}) & 0 & -2/5+2/(5\sqrt{6})\\
0 & 1/\sqrt{6} & 0\\
-2/5+2/(5\sqrt{6}) & 0 & 4/5+1/(5\sqrt{6})\end{array}\right].$$

Then since $A = TS^{-1}$,
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/5+4/(5\sqrt{6}) & 0 & -2/5+2/(5\sqrt{6})\\
0 & 1/\sqrt{6} & 0\\
-2/5+2/(5\sqrt{6}) & 0 & 4/5+1/(5\sqrt{6})\end{array}\right].$$

Multiplying this out gives that 
$$ A = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2/\sqrt{6} & 1/\sqrt{6} & 1/\sqrt{6}\\
-1/5-4/(5\sqrt{6}) & 2/\sqrt{6} & 2/5-2/(5\sqrt{6})\\
2/5-2/(5\sqrt{6}) & 1/\sqrt{6} & -4/5-1/(5\sqrt{6})\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: But if my $S$ is correct, how come I get an incorrect $A$ with the formula $A=TS^{-1}$? I've tested it many times with Maple...

Comment: Checking in MATLAB, I get an $A$ which is orthogonal and $T=AS$. I'll show my work in my answer.

Comment: I'll appreciate that.

Comment: Your calculations are correct. So were mine. It just turns out that Maple is utterly useless for matrix operations...

Comment: Cool. To check the polar decomposition, it is useful to know the following iterative method for calculating $S$,

Comment: $S_0=I$, $S_{n+1}=\tfrac{1}{2}\left(S_n+S_{n}^{-1}U\right)$, where $U=T^{T}T$.